# Unable to terminate/kill a subprocess

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, process, subprocess

I have a python script which also starts OpenVPN as a subprocess. However I found myself completely unable to kill the started subprocess.

```
p = Popen(["openvpn", "--config", conf], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
# do some stuff
p.terminate()
# continue to do other stuff
```

I'm monitoring the list of processes with `htop` and OpenVPN just won't stop, until the moment the python script exits.

I've tried to:

- p.terminate()
- p.kill()
- p.terminate(), then p.kill()
- os.kill(p.pid, 0)
- os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
- os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)

I've also added sleep timers before and after the killing attempts, to verify it's not just a timing problem.

No matter what method I tried, the OpenVPN subprocess started by the script just won't die (listed by htop as a running process) until the script exits.

How do I kill the OpenVPN subprocess?

Answer (score -2):

The Linux sub process kill command is kill -9 PID, you have to implement in python.

Comment: That's what `p.kill()` do. According to the doc : `Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child.`